# retrieving php session values to use as variables afterwards?

Tags: php, mysql, variables, session

I have something here that's probably really easy but I've spent the past 30 minutes searching Google without success, so I'm hoping someone can help me with what I'm doing wrong.

I have certain values stores in sessions on the server and I'm trying to retrieve them on a per-user basis to then use in further queries. For some reason however, it's acting as if the value is empty, so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
$session_country = $_SESSION['my_country_code'];
$user_country = $db->get_sql_field("SELECT id FROM db_countries WHERE country_iso_code='".$session_country."'","country");
echo "your country is ";
echo $user_country;
```

I'd greatly appreciate any tips on what I'm doing wrong :(

When I do a:

```
<? print_r($_SESSION['my_country_code']); ?>
```

It's displayed fine without problems!

//EDIT

Here is the code for get_sql_field:

```
function get_sql_field ($query, $field, $null_message = NULL)
    {
            (string) $field_value = NULL;

            $query_result = $this->query($query);

            if ($this->num_rows($query_result))
            {
                    $field_value = $this->sql_result($query_result, 0, $field);
            }
            else
            {
                    $field_value = $null_message;
            }

            return $field_value;
    }
```

Comment: there is obviously a problem with the sql

Comment: Do you properly declare `session_start()` at the top of your script?

Comment: Paste the code for **get_sql_field** and interesting chunk of **db_countries**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're not actually selecting the "country" field (just "id") in your query, but you're trying to access the "country" field. Either select the "country" field or change the second argument of the get_sql_field() call to "id" if that's what you're actually trying to get.

Comment: Wow, that was it! I knew it was something really stupid! Thank you so much :)

Comment: No problem. :) Sometimes it just takes a second pair of eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$session_country = $_SESSION['my_country_code'];
$qry = "SELECT country FROM db_countries WHERE  country_iso_code='".$session_country."'";
$user_country = $db->get_sql_field($qry,"country");
echo "your country is ".$user_country;
```

Comment: How is your suggestion different than what the OP posted (make it more noticable)? Also, how is a "Try this" considered an answer?

Comment: Sorry, i just post my answer; i was testing this code on my localhost, and writing the answer on the same time...i just missed the previous answer